# rendering a form with css in django

Tags: django

I know how to render static content basically. But, when we use `form.as_p` to let django build out the form from the models for us, then, there are no tags exposed, so, how do we format the form with CSS?

Comment: You can add attributes to the widgets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-classes

Comment: Or, don't use as_p, which is just a shortcut.

Comment: @DanielRoseman , you mean there's no downside to not using the `as_p`? I don't know since all I learnt is from tuts.

Comment: You just need to remember to include all the things it does for you (errors, field labels, etc.) See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

Comment: @DanielRoseman , since practically one wouldn't build forms without styling, what's the use of form.as_p?

Comment: Like I said, a quick shortcut to get up and running. But I'm not sure I understand your implication that you can't style things with as_p; of course you can, you can define CSS for labels, inputs/selects, individual elements via their IDs, and and even generic things like `form > p`. It just doesn't give you specific control.

Comment: Well, I don't know a CSS framework, and I'd like to make my own css for labels and input areas of forms, however, tuts teach me to do it via framework that I don't want to learn (yet atleast) and don't understand the above link.... Do you know any places that shows how to do this?